# When do lightsaber wielders adopt holding it backwards?

Tags: star-wars

In the film, Yoda is training some younglings (before Obi-Wan walked in) and they are all holding their lightsabers the 'right way' (i'll call it that for the sake of ease) [image: Yoda and the younglings]

But some wielders, like Ashoka and Starkiller, use a 'reverse grip'. Where do they adopt this style from if they were trained to hold it a different way? I was thinking it could be a metaphor for the fact they are rebels and outcasts because they hold their sabers differently to others, but I'm sure there must be a reason.

Comment: At the point that they can do it the "right way", presumably they're allowed to start improvising and finding out what works for them best. Some will stick with an overhand grip for their entire lives, others will abandon it immediately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "reverse grip" is an ancient Jedi technique and a variant (called "Shien") of [Form V](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_V), one of the 7 Jedi forms. The younglings in the picture in your question are at a very early point in their training, and are only just learning [Form I](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Form_I), the same form Obi-Wan teaches Luke in A New Hope to deflect blaster fire.

During the rest of their training through their childhood and teenage years, Jedi would learn the other forms and most become proficient in their one preferred style. For [Ahsoka Tano](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano) and [Galen Marek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek), their preferred form is the Shien variant of Form V.

It's worth noting, however, that Ahsoka and Galen are largely self-taught. Ahsoka was already proficient in Form V and it's Shien variant when Yoda took her on as a Padawan. Galen's "training" basically consisted of Vader going "here's how a lightsaber works, now become good with it or die".

Answer (score 3):

According to "The Martial Traveler" (https://martialtraveler.wordpress.com/2009/09/19/reverse-grip-or-zatoichi-style/), reverse wielding a sword (otherwise known as "Zatoichi style") is a seemingly counter-intuitive style that has some advantages in conventional sword combat.  It is a style that is well suited to combat in confined spaces.  Whilst I can find no canon example of someone being trained in what is effectively the Zatoichi style in Star Wars, it could be argued that the Jedi would be trained in multiple styles for different scenarios, and it could also be argued that some lightsaber users just favour that style.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked, which is about Star Wars.